# ENSJS library problem reverse resolving addresses to ENS names

Tags: ropsten, ens

I am trying to use the javascript library "@ensdomains/ensjs" to reverse resolve some ethereum addresses in the ROPSTEN network.
The problem I have is that the following instruction :

```
var name = await ens.getName(address)
```

is always returning and object such as **{"name":null}** even when I use addresses such as '*0x123cb34636cce955d7dfa64ee1c1072f49d44800*' that have a corresponding ens name (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/enslookup-search?search=josh.eth).

According to the documentation I found here : https://docs.ens.domains/dapp-developer-guide/resolving-names. Not only the returned value should not be null but it should not be an object either.....

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it does not work is because the address has not been registered in the reverse registry... now the problem is there does not seem to be a reverse registrar in the Ropsten network...